# elasticsearch how to make an AND query work

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I'm new to elasticsearch and i'm trying to get a query that will match text inside a given number of fields AND the query must also include one of the fields in every query - this is php code:

```
$params = [
            'index'=>'people',
            'type'=>'service-user',
            'from'=>0,
            'size'=>2000,
            'body'=>[
                'query'=>[
                    "match"=>[
                      "stage"=>"serviceUser"
                    ],
                    'multi_match'=>[
                        'query'=>$this->formatSearchTerm($searchTerm),
                        "type" => "phrase_prefix",
                        'operator'=>'OR',
                        'fields'=>[
                            'fname',
                            'lname',
                            'MMID',
                            'fullname'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];
```

So here i basically want it to use all the given fields to find the search term AND "stage" field must be "serviceUser", but this is giving me:

> [match] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]

It works ok if i remove the "match" from the query, i'm just not sure how to mix both of these together.

**UPDATE**

I have tried this, with the same error:

```
$params = [
            "index"=>"people",
            "type"=>"service-user",
            "from"=>0,
            "size"=>2000,
            "body"=>[
                "query"=>[
                    "bool"=>[
                        "must" => [
                            "match"=>[
                                "stage"=>"serviceUser"
                            ],
                            "multi_match"=>[
                                "query"=>$this->formatSearchTerm($searchTerm),
                                "type" => "phrase_prefix",
                                "operator"=>"OR",
                                "fields"=>[
                                    "fname",
                                    "lname",
                                    "MMID",
                                    "fullname"
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add multi-match and match inside [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html).

Look this example:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "FIELD": "TEXT"
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "",
            "fields": []
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question, i tried what you said but same error - i have pasted in the new code